# What does ^& mean in a bat script?

Tags: robocopy

According to the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-hpc-server-2008/ff182367(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
robocopy c:\dirA c:\dirB *.* ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 exit 0
```

What does ^& mean in the above command?

Comment: Thanks you very much !